# android: which implicit intent for picking audio files?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

What intent filter should I use to get audio file as result from a external activity?
Also how the result would be returned? As a URI ,explicit path string , File Descriptor or File object?

Answer (score 0):

```
i = new Intent();           
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("audio/*");
```

using this you can get audio file list from directory.

Comment: So resulting content will always be a URI?

Comment: Is there a way to find what intents the calling application send out to know the corresponding intent filter you need to implement?

Comment: I mean how can you find what any of calling application put in intent.setAction() and intent.setType(), So that you can add intent filters to target it

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

Comment: What's its equivalent XML fields... I am making the result giving activity

Comment: this in implicit intent.. why do you need xml?

Comment: I need my activity to be called for returning a result. So I cant set filters in the code instead I need to put it in xml

Comment: create your own . whats the problem there?

Comment: Problem? 
This:
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

what's this string for XML. can't find it